# Friend functions and classes

Tags: c++, oop

Please consider the following code : 
If suppose I want to make make these 2 classes which access the private members of each other then how will this happen? 
 I can't simply move truck class before bus as then again it'll give me error because it won't find class bus declared as friend in truck class..

```
 class bus 
 { 
private:
    int a;
public: 
    friend void truck:: disp(); 
}; 

class truck 
{
private: 
    int x; 
protected: 
    int y; 
public: 
    int z; 
    friend class bus; 
    void disp(); 
};

void bus :: print() 
{ 
truck t; 
t.x = 10; 
t.y = 20; 
t.z = 30; 
cout<<t.x<<" "<<t.y<<" "<<t.z<<endl; 
} 

void truck :: disp() 
{ 
bus b; 
b.a = 100; 
cout<<"Truck here"<<b.a<<endl; 
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: works if you forward declare `bus` then swap the classes over: https://godbolt.org/z/SwAeKi

Answer (score 1):

You can change the definition order of `bus` and `truck`. The friend declaration in `truck` itself would forward declare `bus`, then you don't need to declare `bus` before `truck`.

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/eydnN0Kym2oITU7E)